# Rewrite url facet by taxonomy term machine name

Tags: search, 9

I have a multi-facet search page, with those 2 facets : **poste** and **type_de_contrat** (= internship, open-ended contract...)

It's working fine, but I'd like to rewrite the url, because it looks like this : `?f[0]=poste%3A131&f[1]=type_de_contrat%3A89`, i want to rewrite the taxonomy IDs by the taxonomy machine name.

I've created and activated a ProcessorHandler to achieve this.

```
/**
 *
 * @FacetsUrlProcessor, which can be configured on the Facet source.
 *
 * @FacetsProcessor(
 *   id = "mymodule_processor_handler",
 *   label = @Translation("Gestion 'Type de contrat' preprocess"),
 *   description = @Translation("Permet de preprocess la facette type de contrat."),
 *   stages = {
 *     "pre_query" = 99,
 *     "build" = 99,
 *   },
 *   locked = false
 * )
 */
class TypeContratProcessorHandler  extends ProcessorPluginBase implements BuildProcessorInterface, PreQueryProcessorInterface, ContainerFactoryPluginInterface {

  /**
   * The actual url processor used for handing urls.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\facets\UrlProcessor\UrlProcessorInterface
   */
  protected $processor;

  /** @var \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack*/
  protected $request;

  /**
   * Constructs a new object.
   *
   * @param array $configuration
   *   A configuration array containing information about the plugin instance.
   * @param string $plugin_id
   *   The plugin_id for the plugin instance.
   * @param mixed $plugin_definition
   *   The plugin implementation definition.
   * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack $request
   */
  public function __construct(array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, RequestStack $request) {
    parent::__construct($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition);
    $this->request = $request;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {
    return new static(
      $configuration,
      $plugin_id,
      $plugin_definition,
      $container->get('request_stack')
    );
  }

  /**
   * Gets the Processor.
   *
   * @return \Drupal\facets\UrlProcessor\UrlProcessorInterface
   *   The Processor.
   */
  public function getProcessor() {
    return $this->processor;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function preQuery(FacetInterface $facet) {
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build(FacetInterface $facet, array $results) {
    $current_request = $this->request->getCurrentRequest();
    if ($current_request === NULL) {
      return $results;
    }
    $taxo_name = "type_de_contrat";
    $filter_key = 'f';
    $facet_url_alias = $facet->getUrlAlias();
    /** @var \Drupal\facets\Result\Result $facetResult */
    foreach ($results as &$facetResult) {
      $url = $facetResult->getUrl();
      if ((int) $facetResult->getRawValue() == '') {
        $facetResult->setActiveState(TRUE);
        $url->setRouteParameters([$facet_url_alias => '']);
      }
      else {
        // rewrite here.
        $taxo = Term::load($facetResult->getRawValue())->get('machine_name')->value;
        $url->setRouteParameters([$facet_url_alias => $taxo]);
      }

      $query = $url->getOption('query');
      $facet_list = $query[$filter_key];
      foreach ($facet_list as $index => $item) {
        if (strpos($item, $facet_url_alias) !== FALSE) {
          unset($query[$filter_key][$index]);
        }
      }
      if (empty($query[$filter_key])) {
        unset($query[$filter_key]);
      }
      $url->setOptions(['query' => $query]);
      $facetResult->setUrl($url);
    }
    return $results;
  }

}
```

But with this, when selecting the facet type_de_contract, it's always the same selected taxonomy machine name (*type_de_contrat=internship*), and the facet isn't making any filter anymore...

Answer (score 0):

I used the [facets pretty paths](https://www.drupal.org/project/facets_pretty_paths) contrib module for things like this.

It can be configured like this:

[image]